# How to replace Hocuspocus server by springboot websocket inside a tiptap editor + Hocuspocus Provider app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, websocket, spring-websocket, tiptap

To make the server part as easy as possible, tiptap provides an opinionated server package, called Hocuspocus. It’s a flexible Node.js package, that you can use to build your custom backend. However, I want to use Spring boot websocket and I don't know where to start.

My goal is to create a fullstack app based on springboot and React. I don't know if it is better to choose NextJs rather than a simple React frontend.

Please help me.